# polymer - can't load second component in test file

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have defined a component `<my-panel>` based on the polymer seed-element. I defined a second component `<my-display>` that contains a `<my-panel>` element.

I want to define a stubbed out version of `my-panel.html` alongside it in the `my-panel` component source: `my-panel-stub.html`.

When I'm writing the tests for `<my-display>`, I want to be able to swap out the contained `<my-panel>` element for a `<my-panel-stub>`. I can do this with:

```
replace("my-panel").with("my-panel-stub");
```

My only problem is that when I try to import `my-panel-stub` into the test file, after I've imported `my-display`, ie.

```
<link rel="import" href="../my-display.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/my-panel/my-panel-stub.html">
```

*I get the following error when the tests execute:*

> Error: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'dom-module'. A type with that name is already registered.

It seems that the test file can only import one component?

I can resolve the issue by doing the html import of the stub inside the `my-display` component, ie:

```
<link rel="import" href="../my-panel/my-panel.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../my-panel/my-panel-stub.html" />
```

Then everything works. But the application code shouldn't be referencing this test-specific element.

Is there a better way to import the stub component directly into the test file?